# Combine multiple when condition in Map

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

I have a use-case to join dataframe A with dataframe B and select attributes based on when condition.

```
A.join(B, condition, "left") 
.select (when(A.template == "some_value", B.new_value)
         .when(A.template == "some_value1", B.new_value1)
         .when(A.template == "some_value2", B.new_value2)
         .otherwise(B.some_value3).alias("new_value")
)
```

I have 25 such when condition and I want it to be part of map instead of select statement. Is there a way to do this?

I tried using UDF and map_from_arrays, however not sure how to specify attribute selection from dataframe B.

```
B[my_map.getItem(A.rate_template)].alias("new_value")
```

Comment: you can apply a pd.merge then appy where query as a filter

Comment: are your values and column names is actually formatted like that(value is `some_value2` and pick `some_value2` column)?   If so, there might be a way to write a list comprehension to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Emma, no they are not formatted the exact same way.

Comment: Could you reflect that in your example? Also, could you show what you have in `my_map`?

Answer (score 0):

Probably if you use "left-semi" with a new column that flags the condition needed would be easier. Additionally, maybe using the `pyspark.sql.functions import transform, transform_values, transform_keys` can be an alternative instead of UDF (Avoid it at any costs. if they broke it is really hard to understand why and debug)

Could you please provide some examples of the data frames you are joining?